# Parametric differentiation

Tags: calculus

> Consider the function $y(x)$ defined parametrically through $x(t) = e^{t+1}+1 $, $y(t) = e^{t^2}$ where $t \in \mathbb{R}$ is the curve parameter. (a) Find an expression for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $t$ from this parametric form. (b) Find an explicit expression for $y$ in terms of $x$ that no longer involves $t$. (c) Use the result of (b) to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$  in terms of $x$, and verify that this agrees with what you got in (a).

How do I do this problem? For what it's worth, here's what I have tried:

(a) $\displaystyle \frac{dx}{dt} = e^{t+1}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dt} = 2te^{t^2}$ so $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{2te^{t^2}}{e^{t+1}}$,

(b) $x = e^{t+1}+1 \implies  x-1 = e^{t+1} \implies \log(x-1)-1 = t$ so $y = e^{t^2} = e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}$

(c) However, when I differentiate the result I got in (b) I don't get an answer that agrees with (a).

Comment: It might have been helpful for you to post what you got for the derivative of (b). Did any of the answers show you where you went wrong? (Maybe where you went wrong was just not recognizing that two formulas were actually equal.)

Comment: @DavidK Yes, in hindsight I was failing to recognize how to substitute back $t$ into the equation for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in part (c). It's all good now as I understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From (b), the derivative comes out to be 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{[\log(x-1)-1]^2}\cdot 2[\log(x-1)-1]\cdot \frac{1}{x-1}$$ 
$$=e^{t^2}\cdot 2t\cdot \frac{1}{e^{t+1}}$$
$$=\frac{2te^{t^2}}{e^{t+1}}$$
which is exactly what you have found in (a).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use the chain rule

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice,

setting $t=\log(x-1)-1$ in the result from (a), one should get $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2te^{t^2}}{e^{t+1}}=\frac{2(\log(x-1)-1)e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}}{e^{\log(x-1)-1+1}}$$ $$=\frac{2(\log(x-1)-1)e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}}{e^{\log(x-1)}}$$
$$=\frac{2(\log(x-1)-1)e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}}{x-1}$$
now, from (b), we have $y=e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}$, hence using chain rule
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2})$$
$$=e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}\cdot 2(\log(x-1)-1)\cdot \frac{1}{x-1}$$
$$=\frac{2(\log(x-1)-1)e^{(\log(x-1)-1)^2}}{x-1}$$
Both the results from (a) & (b) are same